# How can I extract each value of a column from a Feature Collection and append it to a new list in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, feature-collection

**I want to map a function over a Feature Collection to extract some column values and turn it into a list.**

I do know how to map a function over collections, but I'm new with Google Earth Engine and I don't know very well javascript, so I don't know how to work with lists and other features from this language.

Comment: What is the script that you tried out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `.aggregate_array('property')`, this returns an array of values of the selected property.

See also [ee.FeatureCollection.aggregate_array](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefeaturecollectionaggregate_array)